# How to get max results from SQL Query?

Tags: sql, netsuite, suiteql

I have a very simple query and I'm stucked trying to filter only the MAX(b.id) :

```
SELECT 
A.id,
b.id
from emp A
JOIN ACS B
ON B.id = A.id
and A.id =1553
```

In table B, we have three lines for the A.ID. I need to get only the higher one.
I tried to use "MAX(B.ID)" but it didn't worked.

These are the results:

```
[
     {
          "rownumber": 1,
          "A.id": 1553,
          "b.id": 749
     },
     {
          "rownumber": 2,
          "A.id": 1553,
          "b.id": 4356
     },
     {
          "rownumber": 3,
          "A.id": 1553,
          "b.id": 4661
     }
]
```

I just need to return the MAX(b.ID). In this case, I need only:

```
     {
          "rownumber": 3,
          "emp_id": 1553,
          "id": 4661
     }
```

I'll remove the A.id from filter selection and for each line in A I need only the MAX from B.

Thanks in advance!

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to use `RANK()`.

Try this:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT 
  A.id,
  b.id,
  RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY b.ID desc) as rnk
from emp A
JOIN ACS B
  ON B.id = A.id
  and A.id =1553
) as r
where rnk=1
```

Comment: HI Arun! Thanks for your reply! This A.id =1553, and I'm only using to test the results. But I need to run this query to get all the results from all lines from emp A. If I remove the "and A.id = 1553" it will only return the MAX from the entire table and only one line

Comment: @eklon, Providing sample data would be helpful. Because we're joining on ID then how do we get more than 1 matched to `emp` table?

Comment: Hi Arun! The query works for the mentioned ID. But I need to run it without any ID's.
This is the complete query:
https://pastebin.com/3A2c6JWq

Comment: I guess you are looking for `RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY b.ID desc) as rnk` in select statement. try it. I have also updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I'm still with the problem. My query is this one
https://pastebin.com/v3kzTuwW
The table B is the one that have three lines for each line in A, for each employee. And I need to isolate only the newest one from table B.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for me to help?

Comment: Sure, @Arun
Running this query: https://pastebin.com/EvjysJxs
I got these results : https://pastebin.com/DPn0S1z3

Comment: @eklon, Okay here is what I don't understand. **1.** If we join the tables on ID, then how do we have more than 1 B.ID for A.ID?? **2.** If some other column is causing this multiple row issue, please put that column in `ORDER BY` statement inside RANK and try. I hope I was clear

Comment: Hi @Arun! This is the main issue. This case is an employee vs bank account issue. For some employees we have more than one bank account registered. And that's why I need to get the higher ID, considering that it is probably the newest. So, for each employee, I need to get the higher ID from bank accounts table.

Answer (score 1):

As you only want the `id` from `ACS` you can use a *correlated subquery*

```
select e.id, (select Max(id) from ACS a where a.id = e.id) id
from emp e
where e.id = 1553;
```

Comment: Hi Stu! Thanks for your reply! But... I using only the ID's to simplify the question here. I need more field from both table (emp and ACS) . And I'm not able to use this way, right?